# How to fetch record using "Not In" oracle

Tags: oracle

how to fetch oracle result using not in clause where if filter key has value then records should filter according to the filter key, if filter key value is null then to fetch all row using same query?

```
 select * from master_curtomers 
 where cus_index not in (pid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply use an or clause

```
where ((pid is not null and cus_index not in (pid))
        or pid is null)
```

which, I think could be simplified to

```
where (cus_index not in (pid) or pid is null)
```

as `NOT IN (NULL)` will return no rows

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you are asking but this is a very common pattern:

```
select * 
from table
where (id=p_id or p_id is null)
```